# I'm confused about how to calculate noise for an SNR?

Tags: rf, radio, snr

My Rx radio is getting -60 dBm but I don't know how to find the noise. My thermal noise is on the order of E-12 so it barely affects my SNR. Where does noise come from and how can I calculate it?

Answer (score 2):

> Where does noise come from?

Any electrical resistance above absolute zero produces thermal noise.

> how can I calculate it?

It can be modeled as a small AC voltage source in series with the resistor. The thermal voltage RMS value is: -

[image]

Where k is Boltzmann's constant, T is temperature in kelvin, R is the resistance and B is the bandwidth. You could also use a calculator like [**this one**](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Thermal-Noise-Calculator.phtml).

Comment: Thermal noise can also come from an antenna pointed at objects that are at a temperature above absolute zero.

Answer (score 1):

Thermal noise (at room temperature) is -174 dBm/Hz.  You need to scale up the noise for bandwidth and for the noise figure (i.e. excess noise) of your receiver front end.  At radio frequencies, front end noise scales with bandwidth, so in dB it will be 10 log (B), where B is the bandwidth in Hz.  Noise figure is also quoted in dB and it depends on the receiver front end losses as well as the quality of the front end amplifier and mixer.

Comment: Can you please quote a source for this thermal noise figure. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can compute it based on the answer above from Andy aka.  k = 1.38e-23.  Select T=290 (K), R = 1 (ohm) and B = 1 (Hz). Vth = 126.5e-12.  P = Vth^2 =

Comment: Sorry, I got timed out before I could finish my comment.  Above is not correct, you need to take into account the voltage is split between the source and load.  So power is 1/4 of the above.  See Microwave Engineering by David Pozar, Chapter 10.

Comment: I was actually confused about value of R. Hence the question. I was wondering if you'd taken impedance of free space or something else for R. Based on your reply,  your figure was -174 dBm/Hz.Ohm . Would you call that correct?

Comment: Noise power is usually independent of the characteristic impedance.  You can see above the noise voltage scales with the square root of R.  When you compute the power P = V^2/R, the resistance cancels.